# Why some operations on tensors don't give a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, tensor

I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801095/why-some-operations-on-tensors-dont-give-a-tensor) on math.stackexchange but no one seemed to have an authorative answer so I'm posting here hoping that experts will see it.

The gradient is a tensor $\nabla f:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ where the partial derivatives are evaluated at some point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. And evaluation of this linear form at some vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ gives

$$
(\nabla f)(\mathbf{v}) = \partial_x f v_1 + \partial_y f v_2 + \partial_z f v_3
$$
Furthermore in going to a new coordinate system these partial derivatives transform in the expected way.

But what about a function $g:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ which is defined only using the partial derivative of $f$ in the $x$ direction.
$$
g(\mathbf{v}) = \partial_x f v_1 + \partial_x f v_2 + \partial_x f v_3
$$
As I understand this is not considered a tensor because in moving to a new coordinate system it does not transform correctly.

This has confused me endlessly. The strict definition considers a map such as $f:\mathbf{V}\times\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ a tensor if linearity holds in each parameter. The function $g$ above certainly satisfies that. It seems to me that this definition is not used and that the definition of a tensor that is actually used consists of two parts.

- linearity in each parameter (i.e. multilinear form),
- and the algebraic structure of the coefficients is maintained in coordinate transformation

Because once we have calculated $\partial_x f$ it is just a scalar and we just hit $(\partial_x f,\partial_x f,\partial_x f)$ with the usual transformation for a covariant vector to get the new coefficients for $g$ in the new coordinate system. That these new coefficients don't have the right algebraic structure doesn't make multilinearity of $g$ go away. Is this at all correct?

Comment: One reason for a lack of authoritative answer could be want of a definition.  Any of your $g$s, which is on $V^3$, not $V$, is (canonically identified with an element of $(V^*)^{\otimes3}$, so a mathematician might say (as you do) that it is a tensor.  What $g$ you get, and hence with which element it is identified, depends on the coördinates used to take the partial derivative of $f$, so a physicist might care to argue that it is not a tensor.  To answer your question of who is right, we need a definition.  What definition do you want to use?

Comment: Indeed, a physicist would balk at more than one of the premises. First, that "$\partial_{x} f$ is just a scalar". It's not, it's the first component of a vector, which is not the same thing. But, let's indulge and interpret this as "in some fixed coordinate system, I have calculated $h=\partial_{x} f $, and I declare this $h$ that I have obtained a scalar." But then, secondly, $(h,h,h)$ is not a vector - after all, it doesn't change upon transformation. You don't get to "hit it with the usual transformation", you must *show* that it behaves according to that transformation - which it doesn't.

Comment: Your $g(\mathbf{v}) = \partial_x f v_1 + \partial_x f v_2 + \partial_x f v_3$ formula is not a well defined function $g:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: The behaviour of tensors (1-forms in your case) under coordinate changes is a necessary condition for your g functions to be well defined (that is: independent of the coordinate system adopted to describe the vector space V=R^3).

Comment: Is $\mathbf V$ an abstract vector space or is it $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou That g is well defined is exactly the whole point of my post. See the comment by Stinking Bishop in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801095/why-some-operations-on-tensors-dont-give-a-tensor where he elaborates on this.

Comment: @DeaneYang V is meant to be R^3.

Comment: @user782220, i think that the comment from the other site, essentially says the same thing (although not in a clear manner): that your g is not actually a function. So $(\partial_x f , \partial_x f  , \partial_x f)$ is not really a 1-form (a (0,1) tensor). Does this answer your question?

Comment: For me it’s easier to understand if you work with an abstract vector space. Then there are no coordinates already defined. A tensor, such as the gradient, is well defined without any use of coordinates.. You get the formula you wrote only after you choose coordinates, say, by choosing a basis. But since the second formula requires coordinates to define and changes meaning in different coordinates, it can’t be a tensor.